# Reusing function within different functions (new array from each) - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function

Have an array which is being compiled based on user input selection (checkbox and radio buttons)
This is being compiled using an input on change function.

The array is then used to check if values in the array match data attributes referenced within each card, and those which match, show the respective card.

This is working fine.

I am now trying to get the same functionality, but instead of being based on user input, the result is being compiled based on user query string (string is also compiled from the user input - effectively saving a query for using to return to page with results without having to enter the checkbox values again). This function has a lot of if true, push which I would like to re-use instead of re-write. I have simplified here.

Problem I am having is using the same function I built for show/hide the card based on user input with the query string.

```js
// Set Globals:
var arr = []

function buildResults() {
  // Build query based on input values and push into array:
  $("input").on("change", function() {
    var arr = [];

    $(":checkbox").each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        arr.push($(this).val());
      }
    });

    $(":radio").each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        arr.push($(this).val());
      }
    });

    console.log(arr);

    // Join array using unique string
    var vals = arr.join("--");

    // Set URL to pin query to and begin pushing values to string:
    var urlBegin = "https://thisisatest/?results=";
    var str = vals;
    $("#val").text(urlBegin + vals);
    $("#query").text(vals);
    $("#copyTarget").val(urlBegin + vals);
    userSelection = arr;
    resRec();
  });
}

buildResults();

function resRec() {
  // Show div based on user checkbox values:
  var user = userSelection;
  var dataRec = [];
  var recordResultCount = 0;
  console.log(user);

  var first = user.includes("123");
  
  if (first == true) {
    dataRec.push(123456);
  }

  var recordResults = [...new Set(dataRec)];
  recordResultCount = recordResults.length;
  console.log(recordResultCount);

  // Show only the records needed:
  $(".card").each(function() {
    var recordFound = $.inArray($(this).data("recordid"), dataRec);
    if (recordFound === -1) {
      $(this).parent().addClass("destroy");
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("destroy");
    }
  });
}

function resQuery() {
  var urlQuery = window.location.href.match(/results=(.+)/)[1];
  console.log(urlQuery);
  user = urlQuery;
}

// If user enters page via unique query only, and not from page start:
$(function() {
  if (window.location.pathname == "https://thisisatest/?results=") {
    // reuse resRec() here, but using urlQuery and not userSelection;
    var user = resQuery();
    resRec();

    // and show only the cards which match the results built from query
  }
});

resQuery();
```

Function reuse is still new to me, and while I think my logic is on the correct path, I am still getting resRec() not defined.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps because the `buildResults()` is called immediately after the function's definition, which is also at a point _before_ the `resRec` function is defined? ... Maybe try moving the `buildResults()` call to a point _after_ where the `resRec` function is defined.

Comment: Thank you Paul. This was exactly my problem.